# Is it possible to install a H.264 software codec to Google's native Android WebRTC libraries?

Tags: android, webrtc, openh264

According to this post ([How to detect Android H.264 hardware acceleration capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166122/how-to-detect-android-h-264-hardware-acceleration-capability?rq=1)) and also personal experience, the latest Android native libraries for WebRTC ('org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.23546') do not support H.264 unless there is a hardware decoder present for it.

So far, this only effects me when using the emulator, but I understand that some devices it won't work, so that could to be a large problem.

Cisco has their H.264 software decoder available at https://github.com/cisco/openh264 and I'd like to know if there is a way to use that or something else to install software H.264 in a way that will work with WebRTC on devices that don't have hardware decoding.

Additionally, I can't seem to find a support matrix for H.264 hardware decoding on devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using JCodec. Google provides access to create a custom decoder in Java.

-- Decoder.decodeFrame is already in YUV format

-- Data for Y,U,V can be found at frame.getPlaneData(0/1/2)

-- StrideY/U/V is frame.getWidth() >> frame.getColor().compWidth[planeIndex]

-- According to the header in "org.jcodec.common.model.Picture" data is shifted by 128. Necessary to adjust by (byte) (a[i] + 128).